# Where is my crontab file?

Tags: script, cron

I want to edit my crontab file to schedule a script. Where do I find it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you don't want to use `launchd`, you can edit your crontab as you would do on any unix systems :

> crontab -e

Or, you can use a GUI software like [CronniX](http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/).

Comment: And if you want to see your crontab content use crontab -l

Comment: I would highly recommend CronniX. It provides a much (much!) easier way of setting up cronjobs.

Comment: answering a different question

Comment: @Lloyd I would note the OP thinks that this HAS answered the question so they have explicitly said that this DOES answer the question

Answer (score 39):

In Mac OS X Lion the user `crontabs` are stored in `/var/at/tabs`. In the past they were located in `/var/cron/tabs`.

You should use `crontab -e` to interact with these in general, but knowing the location is useful for when you want to restore them from a backup of your disk, or something similar.

**Updated 2022-01**:

- `/var` is a link to `/private/var/`.
- `/usr/lib/cron` is a link to `/var/at`.

The real primary directory is `/private/var/at` with the crontab files being stored in `/private/var/at/tabs`

Comment: In Snow Leopard, the user crontabs are stored in /var/cron/tabs, as well.

Comment: On my mac (v10.11, el capitan) I found it in `/private/var/at/tabs/`. I used `find / -iname *cron*`.

Comment: AlexMA is correct, and on 10.12 (and above) you may need to become 'root' to have permission to access these tables, which have usernames.  I use 'sudo bash' to become 'root', and 'exit' when I'm done.

Comment: Apparently on newer versions, crontabs are stored under: `/usr/lib/cron/tabs`. Although, you need root permission to view the contents of that folder.

Comment: All these files are headlined with `# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall`

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted that if you aren't accustomed to using vim (the default crontab editor) then you can specify your editor as follows:

```
VISUAL=nano crontab -e
```

Answer (score 5):

The OS X way is to use [launchctl](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html) to run jobs at a time.

For ease of use there are GUIs called [Launch Control](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) and [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/).

Comment: answering a different question

Comment: @Lloyd - The question is how to schedule a script . crontab is just how you do that on many Unixes but on macOS you use launchctl

Comment: read your answer again and ask whether it answers "Where is my crontab file?".. that's the original question and my question too.

Comment: The answer is you don't do that on macOS you use another method. The end result is scheduling a script and that is what matter Using crontab is using the wrong tool so it is better to suggest the better way. I read the question as "I want to .... to schedule a script." Look at the required end result not the method to do it which happens to be not the best for macOS.