# Where are crontab files stored in OS 10.8

Tags: macos, cron

I've already looked at this question:

[Where is my crontab file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/where-is-my-crontab-file)

But there is no real answer except for 10.7.  I'm trying to migrate crontab from an old drive that I can't boot so using `crontab -e` is out of the question.  Just need to read the user crontab file to pull existing jobs to a new server.

Comment: Did you try the way described in the answer for 10.7? Are you sure there are any crontabs at all?

Comment: Did you attempt to read the manual? Try- `man 8 cron`

Comment: Nope, @fd0, I didn't.  But now that I have I can see the answer.  Thank you!  Simple as this is, I think it's worth adding as an answer which I'd certainly accept if you want.  If you choose not to, I will add it myself for the benefit of others.

Comment: @patrix - yes there are crontabs and yes I checked in `/var/cron/tabs` but they are not there in 10.8.  As noted in the `man` entry they are in fact in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs`.

Comment: The actual and true location is `/private/var/at/tabs/` as both `/var` and the `/cron` in  `/usr/lib/cron/tabs` are symlinks!

Comment: Closed as dup as the OP didn‘t check whether the answer to the original question actually also worked for versions > Lion.

Answer (score 0):

My current version is 10.8 after check :

```
  /var/at/tabs
```

and name of file is value of logged => $user .

For my comp :

```
  /var/at/tabs/nikola
```

Don't change permission use vim or nano ...